# Hand Gesture Recognition in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to detect hand gestures (wave of hand towards right/left/up/down) through front camera in iPhone/iPad ?

I have seen the link http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/api/ios.html.
But its API is not available.

Comment: No built in framework. and link you have shared has contact email (nanogest@nanocritical.com.)

Comment: I have mailed them.But no reply   :(

Comment: Hey Alen ! I came across Nanogest while searching for Air Gesture libraries but alas there is no Framework in its API page. What did you do? Do you know about any other such library?

Comment: No improvement. Got stucked up.   
I was unable to find another breakthrough.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in framework for that in Cocoa Touch. You would have to implement it yourself or use a third party solution.

Comment: What about the very same implementation in Android ?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Android.